# Circular Matrix Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have the following $N\times N$ [circular matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix):

$$ \left[ \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 2 & .... & N \\
        N & 0 & 1 & .... & N-1 \\
        . & . & . & .... & . \\
        . & . & . & .... & . \\
. & . & . & .... & . \\
1 & 2 & 3 & .... & 0 \\
        \end{matrix} \right] $$
how to prove it's a [linearly independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) matrix?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please check out the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to increase readability of your question. Also, please provide a definition of (or a link to a definition of) a circular matrix, as well as a linearly independent matrix.

Comment: You have provided a link to the definition of a linearly independent set of vectors. I see no definition of a linearly independent matrix. Also, the matrix you have written up is not a circulant matrix, according to the definition you have provided.

Comment: @user161825 the provided circular matrix in my question consist of a set of vectors, who i want to know if they are linearly dependent  or independent

Comment: That clears up some of the confusion! However, $C$ as it is written in your question is a $1\times n$ matrix which does not satisfy the definition that you have linked to.

Comment: @user161825 "in circular matrix each row vector is rotated one element to the right relative to the preceding row vector" so for example row 2 is [N, 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1] and so on .. that's a well known property for circular matrix so i write it in that compact way

Comment: Even though it is a well known property, your question would be easier to read if you wrote the matrix out in full (see the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to write matrices). How many rows does your matrix have?